# How do I divide a long survey of many questions over multiple users?

Tags: statistics

I am developing a survey website. The surveys are quite long (75 questions) so I want to divide the questions over multiple users. Example numbers:

- Survey length: 75 questions
- Users: 100
- Questions per user: 15
- Answers per question: 20

So, I want to ask every user 15 questions which will get me 20 answers per survey question.

My question: How do I divide the questions over the users properly? I have multiple properties per user that I would like to take into account (e.g. "team" and "gender"). I know the make-up of the full population and I know that my 100 selected users accurately reflect the full population (I used stratified randomization to select the 100 users).

Ideally, I would also like to take previous answers into account. Say I run this type of survey every month. I would prefer it if users do not get too many duplicate questions. I.e. if Bob answered question 10 last month, I would prefer his list of 15 questions to not include question 10.

Is there any good statistical or mathematical way to distribute the questions over the users so that the answers will reflect the total population?

Comment: Depends on the extent to which you wish to investigate associations btw answers to various questions. (If you want to see if favorable on 10 and favorable on 23 tend to be associated, then some of the same people have to answer both.) // Tendency in such a project is to ask waaay too many questions. If associations important, could you deal with fewer questions? Think hard before you say No. Do you have plans how to analyze if some subjects drop out due to the nr of questions> // If questions can be sorted into subtypes, consider one question of each type to each user each time.

Comment: Non-responses should be no problem. This is for employee satisfaction. Taking the survey is mandated by management. Questions are split into subtypes (blocks of questions relating to a particular aspect of employee satisfaction) so I will try to split up the survey that way. Thanks!